# What is the time complexity to insert M elements in a singly circular ordered list?

Tags: linked-list, time-complexity, insertion, circular-list

```
On a singly circular ordered list having N elements and 
if M elements are to be inserted what will be the complexity of time?


a) O(M*N)

b) O(M*(M+N))

c) O((M+N) * log(M+N))
```

I think, the time taken to do this work should be `O(N + M)`. Because we need `O(N)` to find the last element and `O(M)` to insert all the elements after it and linking will take `O(1)`.

---

Also, I find the word `Ordered` a little bit confusing, is it `Sorted` or `Preserving Natural Ordering`.

If `Ordered` means `Preserving Natural Ordering` then I think `O(N + M)`.

and if `Sorted` then `O(N * M)`

Comment: The idea is that if the list is ordered, in the worst case you'll need to traverse the entire list to insert each element at the end. The list will start with N elements and grow to N+M elements. It's average length for each insertion will be N+M/2. You'll traverse that length M times. Consequently, total elements traversed will be roughly M(M/2 + N), which is O(M*(M+N)) time. Note though the question isn't worded very well, it seems they are asking for the time to complete all M insertions, not each insertion (amortized).  Amortized time for each insertion would require dividing by M: O(M+N).

Comment: Thanks @Gene. But I didn't get the "It's average length for each insertion will be N+M/2." part. Could you please explain this?

Comment: To be precise, to get to the end of the list, the first insertion will traverse a list of length N, the second N+1, then N+2, etc. up to N+M.  Sum all these. By well known identities, you'll get MN +  M(M+1)/2.  The average of these is M(N + (M+1)/2) / M = N + (M+1)/2. This is pretty close to N+M/2 as I said.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a sorted case scenario and not "Preserving Natural Ordering", and we will be calculating frequency for the complete operation of insertion(all m elements), hence O(M*N) seems to be the case if we assume value of N is way higher compared to M